# ¿Cómo manejar un condicional en esta colección?

Tags: laravel

Hago una consulta y al imprimir el contenido `dd($examples)` me muestra el siguiente código:

```
^ Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1308 ▼
  #items: []
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

Necesito hacer un condicional pero no sé como utilizar el valor que retorna, intenté con `@if(empty($examples))` y también con `@if($examples->isEmpty)` pero no lo toma, asumo que lo que está regresando no es un valor vacío

Mi consulta:

```
$examples= Example::where('status', '<>', 'Deleted')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
return view('home', compact('examples'));
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado usar `->count() == 0`?

Comment: No, la verdad no tenía idea que hacer con esa respuesta... Lo intentaré!

Comment: Hola. Cuando se utiliza isEmpty, este siempre se usa con parentesis, por ejemplo ->isEmpty()

Comment: Muchas gracias a Ambos! Las dos opciones me funcionaron.